# jquery - how to add fadein/fadeout to mouseover background changing code

Tags: jquery, background-image, fadein, fadeout

I have this code that changes background image of a div when you hover over a link:

```
<script>

$('.main').on('mouseover', 'a', function () {

var background = "url('" + $(this).attr('data-background') + "')";

$('.main').css('background-image', background)
});

</script>
```

and html that goes with it..

```
<div style="background: #f2f2f2 no-repeat center; background-size:100% auto;" class="main">
<div id="logo"></div>
<div class="center-inner">
<h3>
<a href="#" data-background="img/img1.jpg">img1</a> 
<a href="#" data-background="img/img2.jpg">img2</a> 
<a href="#" data-background="img/img3.jpg">img3</a>
</h3></div>
<div id="copyright"><p>©2013</p></div>
</div>
```

How can I add fade in and fade out (on mouseout) effects to this code?

Thank you!

Comment: `.fadeOut()` the div first, then set its background, then `.fadeIn()`?

Comment: @nnnnnn It's not good idea, because the element that is responsible to show the `background-image`, contents text within itself.

Comment: @NOX - I was just trying to give the OP a hint to get them started. A hint that is, as it turns out, pretty much what you did in your answer once you added the extra div.

Comment: @nnnnnn I understand, tnx ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uvJpd/1/)**

Add another element for your `background` container and change its opacity.

### HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="bg"></div>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div class="center-inner"><h3>
        <a href="#" data-background="http://placekitten.com/200/200">img1</a> 
        <a href="#" data-background="http://placekitten.com/200/200">img2</a> 
        <a href="#" data-background="http://placekitten.com/200/200">img3</a>
    </h3></div>
    <div id="copyright"><p>©2013</p></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.main, #logo, .center-inner, #copyright {
    position: relative;
}

#bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #f2f2f2 no-repeat center; background-size:100% auto;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $('.main').on('mouseover', 'a', function () {
        var background = "url('" + $(this).attr('data-background') + "')";

        $('#bg')
            .stop()
            .css('opacity', 0)
            .css('background-image', background)
            .animate({opacity: 1});
    });
});
```